# rm -rf doesnt clean the directory completely

Tags: windows, makefile, file-permissions, permission-denied, rm

First of all, this is a windows system, not linux. 
In the makefile I have, for make clean I am doing

```
rm -rf output
```

However, the first time it runs, it gives an error like

```
rm: cannot lstat `foo.txt': Permission denied
```

Even though the directory output is completely empty after the execution of the command. Now if I run the command second time,

```
rm -rf output
```

It deletes `output` successfully. Any idea as to why it didnt work the first time? And the file foo.txt is not open anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Windows is the problem here.

I assume you're running in CygWin, and there's something in the background getting in your way.. There are too many possibilities to count:

- Antivirus?
- Recycle Bin?
- Application Experience Engine?

This has been a long-running bug for the Bugzilla folks for a while, look at [bug 545015](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=545015).. They solved it via:

> 1. In the local group policy editor:
>      Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates
>      -> Windows Components -> Application Compatibility
>
> Select Turn Off Application Compatibility Engine
>   Select Enabled under the Settings tab
>   Select Turn off Program Compatibility Assistant
>   Select Enabled under the Settings tab
>
> 1. Turn off the file indexation and the application experience services.
> 2. Reboot.

Comment: The usual workaround (which has always been successful for me) is to issue the remove command twice.  I've never yet seen the second remove operation fail - though I'm working directly in Windows rather than via Cygwin.